# PHP write to file on external server

Tags: php, external, fopen

I am trying to write to file on external server with php. I have the FTP details.
Here is my code

```
$handle = fopen("ftp://USN:PASS@DOMAIN/FOLDER/FILE.HTML", "a");

fwrite($handle, "Some text");

fclose($handle);
```

upon execution I get "The connection was reset. The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading." error in browser.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your error log? Is that an error from the webpage or from the ftp request?

Comment: It is not form the FTP request. Is the code wrong?

Comment: You likely need to use the [ftp functions](http://www.php.net/ftp). I don't believe fopen will "speak" the ftp protocol. If you can't use the ftp functions, then you would likely need to find (or write your own) object to handle it using fsockopen.

Comment: First check your logs, then be sure you have `allow_url_fopen` set as true in your php.ini or change it in execution mode with this code: `ini_set("allow_url_fopen ", 1);`.

Comment: I don't have access to my php.ini. I'm using 000webhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works in my local server so this approach is absolutely possible. I guess 000webhost has set

```
ini_set("allow_url_fopen ", 0);
```

in php.ini